# Constants DL and Fiddle is not defined

Tags: ruby, aspose.words, rjb

I am trying to run asposewords for ruby. I check configuration found nothing problem with them. But on running I get this error

> /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rjb.rb:47:in `load': Constants DL and Fiddle is not defined. (RuntimeError)

I think I have a problem with my rjb, but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-diagram/issues/42

Comment: What's your Ruby version? Does `require 'fiddle'` succeed in `irb` (or try `ruby -rfiddle -e "Fiddle"`)?

Comment: The answer to this question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71049761/2257185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for using Aspose.Words Java for Ruby. Currently we support the following platforms:

Ruby 2.2.x or above and respective DevKit.
Java 1.5 or above

Can you please check and confirm which Ruby version you are using?

For more details you can go through the documentation page http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/Aspose.Words+Java+For+Ruby

If you still face any issues, please let us know and we will be glad to help.