# Ruby 2.5.1, Ruby Java Bridge (RJB), and Ubuntu 18.04: Getting `Constants DL and Fiddle is not defined.`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rjb

I need help.  I can't figure out why I can't boot my Rails 5.2 app now that `rjb` is a dependency.  I keep getting a generic error about `Constants DL and Fiddle is not defined.`

First, yes I have read the [Documentation](https://www.artonx.org/collabo/backyard/?RubyJavaBridge).

Second, yes I have set `JAVA_HOME`.

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Third, I have set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (COULD THIS BE THE PROBLEM?)

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64
```

However, whenever I try to open `rails console` or `rails server` I just get the error:

```
$ rails c
/home/daniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:84:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'fillable-pdf'.
Gem Load Error is: Constants DL and Fiddle is not defined.
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@fuel/gems/fillable-pdf-0.6/lib/fillable-pdf/itext.rb:4:in `load'
....    
<redacted>
```

The app runs fine on OSX, on CircleCI, and on Heroku.  Does someone with more experience with `rjb` than me spot what I'm missing here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After rebooting and running some updates, it seems to work now.  So all of the above appears to be correct.  No JVM issues when opening up `rails console` anymore.

Comment: For others experiencing the same error, the answer here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71049761/2257185